# Paypal cancel subscription created via paypal standard subscription button

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I use paypal standard subscription button for manage subscription system in my site
I configure ipn i got 2 ipn notification with txn_type **subscr_signup** and **subscr_payment** and i have **subscr_id** param there also.
So i have few questions:

1) how can i get subscription state (active, suspend, canceled, etc) by subscr_id? (i tried GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails but it can be used when subscription was created by express checkout only). i getting error 'Subscription Profiles not supported by Recurring Payment APIs'.

2) how to manage subscription state by subscr_id? (also tried ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus, but getting error 'The profile ID is invalid'  all the time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "[TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/)" API to get the details for any profile( even for the one created using the PayPal subscription button ) .With this you can get the info like when profile was created , updated ,suspended etc . I have included the sample request and response , might be it can help you :

**NVP Request:**

```
USER=XXXXXXXXXX&PWD=XXXXXXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=XXXXXX&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=TransactionSearch&STARTDATE=2014-01-24T00:00:00Z&TRANSACTIONCLASS=SUBSCRIPTION&PROFILEID=I-FXMKNUUEP6XL
```

**NVP Response:**

```
L_TIMESTAMP0=2014-02-17T16:19:50Z
L_TIMESTAMP1=2014-02-17T16:19:51Z
L_TIMESTAMP2=2014-03-17T14:02:39Z
L_TIMESTAMP3=2014-04-17T15:26:44Z
L_TIMESTAMP4=2014-05-09T17:18:37Z
L_TIMESTAMP5=2014-05-09T17:19:15Z
L_TIMESTAMP6=2014-05-09T17:19:40Z
L_TIMESTAMP7=2014-05-17T15:26:31Z
L_TIMESTAMP8=2014-06-17T15:55:14Z
L_TIMESTAMP9=2014-07-17T16:14:01Z
L_TIMESTAMP10=2014-08-17T16:06:44Z
L_TIMESTAMP11=2014-09-17T15:55:04Z
L_TIMEZONE0=GMT
L_TIMEZONE1=GMT
L_TIMEZONE2=GMT
L_TIMEZONE3=GMT
L_TIMEZONE4=GMT
L_TIMEZONE5=GMT
L_TIMEZONE6=GMT
L_TIMEZONE7=GMT
L_TIMEZONE8=GMT
L_TIMEZONE9=GMT
L_TIMEZONE10=GMT
L_TIMEZONE11=GMT
L_TYPE0=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE1=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE2=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE3=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE4=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE5=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE6=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE7=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE8=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE9=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE10=Recurring Payment
L_TYPE11=Recurring Payment
L_EMAIL1=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_EMAIL2=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_EMAIL3=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_EMAIL7=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_EMAIL8=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_EMAIL9=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_EMAIL10=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_EMAIL11=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
L_NAME0=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME1=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME2=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME3=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME4=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME5=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME6=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME7=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME8=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME9=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME10=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_NAME11=Eshan Personal Test Account
L_TRANSACTIONID0=I-FXMKNUUEP6XL
L_TRANSACTIONID1=0AR10991U1333214W
L_TRANSACTIONID2=1GX902663D9811358
L_TRANSACTIONID3=0K568033VD746381F
L_TRANSACTIONID4=I-FXMKNUUEP6XL
L_TRANSACTIONID5=I-FXMKNUUEP6XL
L_TRANSACTIONID6=I-FXMKNUUEP6XL
L_TRANSACTIONID7=4A4539330Y180244M
L_TRANSACTIONID8=94165672XW4156934
L_TRANSACTIONID9=12791760JH4394641
L_TRANSACTIONID10=36E095146V2526231
L_TRANSACTIONID11=5ED26578AA878723D
L_STATUS0=Created
L_STATUS1=Completed
L_STATUS2=Completed
L_STATUS3=Completed
L_STATUS4=Updated
L_STATUS5=Updated
L_STATUS6=Updated
L_STATUS7=Completed
L_STATUS8=Completed
L_STATUS9=Completed
L_STATUS10=Completed
L_STATUS11=Pending
L_AMT1=50.00
L_AMT2=50.00
L_AMT3=50.00
L_AMT7=50.00
L_AMT8=50.00
L_AMT9=50.00
L_AMT10=50.00
L_AMT11=50.00
L_CURRENCYCODE1=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE2=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE3=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE7=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE8=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE9=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE10=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE11=USD
L_FEEAMT1=-1.75
L_FEEAMT2=-1.75
L_FEEAMT3=-1.75
L_FEEAMT7=-1.75
L_FEEAMT8=-1.75
L_FEEAMT9=-1.75
L_FEEAMT10=-1.75
L_FEEAMT11=0.00
L_NETAMT1=48.25
L_NETAMT2=48.25
L_NETAMT3=48.25
L_NETAMT7=48.25
L_NETAMT8=48.25
L_NETAMT9=48.25
L_NETAMT10=48.25
L_NETAMT11=50.00
TIMESTAMP=2014-10-07T11:05:34Z
CORRELATIONID=5bb22082c58de
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=000000
```

Comment: Managing Profile means , You want to change the details for the profile using API?

Comment: the user in my site subscribe to service via button (standart subscription button). Is it possible to allow user cancel his subscription by interface in profile (for example)?

Comment: The user as well the seller can cancel the Profile from their PayPal account any time. Since its a button subscription you can't use all the recurring API with it . However you can use "ManagerRecurringPayments" API to cancel/suspend/reactivate the button profiles and rest of the recurring apis will result in error like"Profile id not supported".

Comment: my users have not paypal account, bcoz they pay via credit card. ofc, i can't use ManagerRecurringPayments, bcoz my profiles creating via standard button (recurring payment api don't allow subscribe with credit card).